# React does not re-render component after setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have a strange problem. `state` is updated, but component is not re-rended. When I push the button `Add Hi All`, additional `<p>Hi All</p>` must be added. But I do not see them on the screen.

The interesting part is that if I change `new_row` to an 1 element array like this

```
var new_row = [<p key = {key_number + "d"}> Hi all!</p>];
```

and then will use `parag_s.concat(new_row)` instead of `parag_s.push(new_row)` everything works fine. The contains of the `state.ps` array seems absolutely identical in both variants but somehow when I use
`parag_s.push(new_row)` re-rendering process does not start.
That’s why I feel I do something wrong. Could you help me? Why the following code does not work?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BlablablaComponent/>
        );
    }
}

class BlablablaComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ps: [],
            keyNumber: 1
        }
        this.addRow = this.addRow.bind(this);
    }

    addRow() {
        var parag_s = this.state.ps;
        var key_number = this.state.keyNumber;
        key_number = key_number + 1;
        var new_row = <p key = {key_number + "d"}> Hi all!</p>;
        parag_s.push(new_row);
        var new_state = {ps: parag_s, keyNumber: key_number};
        this.setState(new_state);
   }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.ps}
                <button type="button" onClick = {this.addRow} >Add Hi All</button> 
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Changing state inside the render function is not recommended. It can also easily lead to an infinite loop (change state -> render -> change state -> render...)

Comment: @Cristy But I do not change state inside render function. I use addRow for this. In render I only read the this.state.ps property (which is array of React objects as I understand). Could you give some more explanation, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` performs a shallow comparison on the array, when you `push` into the array the instance doesn't change therefore React doesn't see a change. When you use `concat` a new array instance is returned.

You could use the spread operator rather than `concat`

```
 setState({
   key_number,
   parag_s: [...parag_s, new_row]
 })
```

Comment: @JamesThank you very much! Could you give a couple more examples when you  change state, but React doesn't see it?

Comment: @BlackBeard `setState` is a complicated process, I can only point you in the direction of the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) if you want to learn more about how it works.